# How can I retrieve contacts list in a fragement android Studio ? where is the problem

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

This is the fragment class where I should display the contacts list. I already checked permissions in the manifest

```
public class ContactsFragment extends Fragment {

    View v;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ContactAdapter contactAdapter;

    public ContactsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts,container,false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
        {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},1);
            return;
        }
        else {
            contactAdapter=new ContactAdapter(getActivity());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            contactAdapter=new ContactAdapter(getActivity());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
        }

    }
}
```

and this is the Activity that contains 2 fragments i don't think that i should display the list of contacts in here

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    //fragements
    private TabsAccessorAdapter myTabsAccessorAdapter;
    private ViewPager myViewPager;
    private TabLayout myTabLayout;



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_profile);

        //toolbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MyBackup");

        //fragements
        myViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.main_tabs_pager);
        myTabsAccessorAdapter = new TabsAccessorAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        myViewPager.setAdapter(myTabsAccessorAdapter);
        myTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
        myTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(myViewPager);

        myTabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_contacts);
        myTabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_sms);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void sendUserToLoginActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        //hna diri backup w restore

        //logout
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.logout_option){
            mAuth.signOut();
            sendUserToLoginActivity();

        }
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (currentUser !=null){
            sendUserToLoginActivity();
        }
    }


}
```

And this is the model class it contains just name, phone number and email

```
public class Contact {

    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String email;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

and this is the `contactAdapter`

```
public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.Viewholder>{
    private List<Contact> data=new ArrayList<>();
    private ContactDao contactDao;
    public ContactAdapter(Context context){
        contactDao=new ContactDao(context);
        data=contactDao.getData();
    }
    public static class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtname;
        TextView txtphone;
        TextView txtemail;
        View v;
        public Viewholder(View v){
            super(v);

            txtname=v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            txtphone=v.findViewById(R.id.phone);
            txtemail=v.findViewById(R.id.email);

        }


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_items, parent, false);
        Viewholder viewholder =new Viewholder(v);
        return viewholder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Viewholder viewholder, int position) {

        viewholder.txtname.setText(data.get(position).getName());
        viewholder.txtphone.setText(data.get(position).getPhone());
        viewholder.txtemail.setText(data.get(position).getEmail());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }



}
```

and this is the `ContactDAO`

```
public class ContactDao {

    private List<Contact> data =new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Contact> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Contact> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public ContactDao(Context ctx)
    {

        Cursor Cursorcontacts=new CursorLoader(ctx, Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null).loadInBackground();
        Contact contact;

        while (Cursorcontacts.moveToNext())
        {
            contact = new Contact();
            contact.setName(Cursorcontacts.getString(Cursorcontacts.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            String Id=Cursorcontacts.getString(Cursorcontacts.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID));

            //Récup les Teles
            String [] PhoneProjection=new String[]{CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
            Cursor cursorPhone=ctx.getContentResolver().query(CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,PhoneProjection,Id+"="+CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,null,null);
            if (cursorPhone.getCount()>0)
            {
                cursorPhone.moveToFirst();
                contact.setPhone(cursorPhone.getString(0));
            }
            //Recup. Email

            String [] EmailProjection=new String[]{CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS};
            Cursor cursorEmail=ctx.getContentResolver().query(CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,EmailProjection,Id+"="+CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID,null,null);
            if (cursorEmail.getCount()>0)
            {
                cursorEmail.moveToFirst();
                contact.setEmail(cursorEmail.getString(0));
            }

            data.add(contact);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when you call contactDao.getData() inside ContactAdapter, which size of getted data ? Did you debug your codebase?

Comment: yes it works when i display it in an activity but not in a fragment